# Wrapping a custom php extension

Tags: php, php-extension, php-internals

I'm trying to wrap a custom php extension from a C library, now I have an Initializer function which initiate a specific custom connection and seems to be expensive one and i should not run it each time I call the function.

Let's suppose that I have the following in the ZEND wrapper,

```
PHP_FUNCTION(get_data){
    conn = conn_init();
    data = getdata(conn);
    return data;
}
```

`conn_init()` is an expensive call here, where should I put that function?

and can I ask users to call `conn_init()` from PHP and how?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you should wrap `conn` as a [resource](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/language.types.resource.php).

Then a script using your extension could look like

```
$conn = YOUREXT_connect($cparams);
$data[1] = YOUREXT_getdata($conn, $params[1]);
$data[2] = YOUREXT_getdata($conn, $params[2]);
$data[3] = YOUREXT_getdata($conn, $params[3]);
```

Comment: Or better yet, make it object oriented.

Comment: That's one of the solutions, but I'm stuck with passing the connection resource to the function in the ZEND wrapper.